# lldb application on mac os

Tags: macos, lldb

I would like to learn to use the lldb debugger on my Mac OSx (Yosemite) as I can't seem to get gdb to work properly (via homebrew).  However I ran into a weird problem and wonder if someone can point me int he right direction.  Basically after I loaded an application into lldb and execute run, it just returns the command prompt with no GUI opening up for the said application.  Attached below is an excerpt of the attempt.  Any idea ?

```
% lldb /Applications/Navicat\ for\ SQL\ Server.app/Contents/MacOS/Navicat\ for\ SQL\ Server 
(lldb) target create "/Applications/Navicat for SQL Server.app/Contents/MacOS/Navicat for SQL Server"
Current executable set to '/Applications/Navicat for SQL Server.app/Contents/MacOS/Navicat for SQL Server' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
Process 2881 launched: '/Applications/Navicat for SQL Server.app/Contents/MacOS/Navicat for SQL Server' (x86_64)
Process 2881 exited with status = 45 (0x0000002d) 
(lldb)
```

Comment: Just a side-note: when you try to debug a process and it exists right away with code 45, most likely the process has called `ptrace(PT_DENY_ATTACH...)` at some point kicking your debugger out. Best way around this is set a breakpoint on ptrace stub and force it to return zero.

Comment: anyone who want more detail about @Sonic comment please read this https://www.coredump.gr/articles/ios-anti-debugging-protections-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your process exited (with status 45) without putting up any GUI.  Try setting a breakpoint on exit:

```
(lldb) break set -n exit
```

before you run, then run and you should hit the breakpoint.  Looking at the backtrace at that point might show you why it was exiting prematurely.

BTW, if you are familiar with gdb, this page might be helpful:

http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

Comment: Also, though this is most likely not the cause of your problem, you don't need to specify the Contents/MacOS/... part of the path to your app, just give lldb up to the .app and it will figure out the binary.